# Excel VBA String Manipulation on a large document caused Runtime error "1004"

Tags: string, vba, excel

So I'm making a visual novel on RenPy and I had to swap out sentences on a whole document.

Since the revision came in an excel file, I decided to use excel macro to do the fix automatically.
There are three columns. Original Line, Suggested Fix, and the raw script.

[image: example]

So I banged out a script which looked like this:

```
Sub MacroVOID()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Long
x = 2
y = 2

Do While x < 298
If StrComp(Cells(x, 1).Value, Cells(y, 3).Value, vBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value
    x = x + 1
    Else
    y = y + 1
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Which caused a Runtime error "1004".

I saved the macro on worksheet level.

I'm a novice at this stuff so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your macro works at the activesheet by lack of a defined worksheet to run on. That might cause you the error. Also you are checking if two strings are equal, and if so replace something. I think you would better read on the syntax of Strcomp: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php

Comment: It's vbBinaryCompare, not vBinaryCompare. I suggest you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your sheet. That will alert you to typos like this one. Adding to what @Luuklag wrote, StrComp compares strings. The two Values you compare are variants, not necessarily strings. You might convert them by using `Cstr(Cells(x, 1).value)` for both values to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceStrings()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<-- Update Sheet Name

    With ws.UsedRange
        For Each cel In .Columns(1).Cells       'iterate through all used cells in col A
            If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then         'if the cell is not empy

                'in column 3: replace all instances of values in current cell
                'with the value in (current cell).offset by one column to its right (col B)
                .Columns(3).Replace cel.Value2, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value2, xlWhole

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

The Range.Replace method has these parameters:

`Replace(What, Replacement, LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat, ReplaceFormat)"`

More details from Help:

- **What**: Required Variant The string you want Microsoft Excel to search for.
- **Replacement**: Required Variant The replacement string.
- **LookAt**: Optional Variant Can be one of the following XlLookAt constants: xlWhole or xlPart.
- **SearchOrder**: Optional Variant Can be one of the following XlSearchOrder constants: xlByRows or xlByColumns.
- **MatchCase**: Optional Variant True to make the search case sensitive.
- **MatchByte**: Optional Variant You can use this argument only if you’ve selected or installed double-byte language support in Microsoft Excel. True to have double-byte characters match only double-byte characters. False to have double-byte characters match their single-byte equivalents.
- **SearchFormat**: Optional Variant The search format for the method.
- **ReplaceFormat**: Optional Variant The replace format for the method.

Comment: Your code worked, but some didn't get replaced? Can you walk me through your code? I want to try to understand it. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Nevermind I found it. It was the tilde. The original had the sideways tilde and the fix had a straight tilde. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: I added more details about each step @RizkyGustiantoWibisono